# Error using Slim Framework (v4) Middleware

Tags: php, api, slim

I'm trying to use a `middleware` in my `Slim route` but i have an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Api\Middleware\Auth::__invoke(), 2 passed

#### I'm trying:

**Index File**

```php
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

use Api\Middleware\Auth;

require __DIR__ . '../../../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->add(new Auth);

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Start Project");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

**Middleware File**

```
<?php

namespace Api\Middleware;

class Auth {
  public function __invoke($request, $response, $next) {
    echo "Middleware";
    return $next($request, $response);
  }
}
```

I'm reading and copying the [docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/concepts/middleware.html) but cannot fix that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation you've linked the middleware in Slim is either the function that takes two arguments, or a object with `__invoke` magic method that takes two arguments. The arguments passed are `Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface` and `Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface`.

Your implementation of middleware is expecting 3 arguments.

It should look like this:

```php
class Auth {
    public function __invoke($request, $handler) {
        echo "Middleware";
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: V4 doc : https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/concepts/middleware.html